# Cout.width() add unexpected 0

Tags: c++, printing, console

```
cout << setw(13) << left << "open <file>" << cout.width(5) << " opens <file>" << endl;
```

This code prints me in the console the following thing:

```
open <file>  0     opens <file>
```

What this 0 doing there? How can i fix it? Thank you so much!

Comment: I forgot to say that im using ecplise c++.

Comment: Did you check the return type and value of [`cout.width(5)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/width)?

Comment: @RSahu Thank you <3.

Comment: Do you have the answer to your question now?

Comment: @RSahu ``cout << setw(13) << left << "open <file>";
   cout.width(5);
   cout << "opens <file>" << endl;``

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from inserting the value returned by `cout.width(5)` into the stream. Either call that on its own:

```
std::cout << std::setw(13) << std::left << "open <file>";
std::cout.width(5);
std::cout << " opens <file>" << '\n';
```

or use `std::setw`:

```
std::cout << std::setw(13) << std::left << "open <file>" << std::setw(5) << " opens <file>" << '\n';
```

Comment: There is no `std::setwidth()` stream manipulator, the correct stream manipulator is [`std::setw()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) instead: `std::cout << std::setw(13) << std::left << "open <file>" << std::setw(5) << " opens <file>" << '\n';`

Comment: @RemyLebeau -- D'oh! Too busy editorializing about `std::` to copy the original code correctly. Fixed, thanks.